# php do something with interval

Tags: php, continuous

i have a form, say like this :

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="tfcari" />
<input type="submit" name="btcari" />
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['btcari'])) {

echo $_POST['tfcari'];  

?>
```

how to doing like this :

> click submit - echo text - wait for 5 seconds - echo text
>   (automatically) - wait for 5 seconds - echo text (automatically) - ...

thanks all.

Comment: Use Javascript or JQuery.

Comment: @Toby `<pedantic>jQuery is JavaScript</pedantic>` :)

Comment: @Phil I knew someone would say that, but the idea of me just writing javascript and somebody actually trying to implement this in plain old javascript without the jquery library rather than just doing it with jquery is too horrible to contemplate.  :)

Comment: @Toby Really? `setTimeout()`, `createTextNode()` and `appendChild()` should be all you need

Comment: @TobyAllen I do like me some vanilla js, though I have to admit that when it comes to XHR, I prefer to lean on jQuery to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @francisco Same here, though I didn't see any XHR requirement in the question above

Comment: @Phil My guess was that he wanted to pull some value from the database and echo it. Suppose I assumed too much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP pre-processes before sending to the website, so if you were to put a sleep method, it would only delay the page frrom displaying for that long.

The -easiest- way will be to use jQuery for an ajax call, then use setTimeout to echo text every 5 seconds:

```
// Assuming jQuery is linked
$(function() {
    // Connect to the php file
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php-file-with-tfcari-var.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            // data is what the ajax call returns, let's assume it's the $_POST variable from php
            var tfcari = data.tfcari;
            // Now you can loop every 5 seconds with a self calling setTimeout method
            var poll = (setTimeout(function() {
                window.document.write(tfcari);
            }, 5000)();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: :) hmm. undrstand know. great explnation, thanks francisco

Comment: sorry for the noobs, i run the code, it like not success? how?